# Find specific column and get values to an array in visual C#

Tags: arrays, datagrid, visual-c#-express-2010

I am trying to refer to a specific column of a DataGrid and get all the values into an array. I don't get any errors but the problem is that only the zeroth position of the array seem to have a value while the other positions are null.There are 4 records in the Datagrid. What am I doing wrong

Here's My code:

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        string[] arr = new string[10];

        DataTable getdata = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[1]; 
            {
                if (cell != null && (cell.Value != null))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        arr[i] = cell.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (arr[0] != null)
        {
            textBox3.Text = arr[0].ToString();//Prints value
        }
        else if (arr[1] != null)//Seems to be null
        {
            textBox2.Text = arr[1].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are looping through rows twice, once in the foreach and once with the for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something likes this instead

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<String> columnValues = new List<String>

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[1]; 
            {
                if (cell != null && (cell.Value != null))
                {
                   columValues.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
                   if (columnValues.Count == 2)
                   {
                      break;
                   }
                }
            }
        }

        if (columnValues.Count > 0)
        {
          if (columnValues.Count < 2)
          {
            textBox3.Text = columnValues[0];//Prints value
          }
          else 
          {
               textBox2.Text = columnValues[1];
          }
        }
    }
```

Didn't like the array. more than 11 non-null values thing would fall over. 
No idea what that datatable was for. 
If you only put non-null value in a collection, why check them for null.
String.ToString() seemed a bit pointless.

Added a break seeing as you were only interested in 2 non-null values.
And squared up that last bit of logic, though I can't come up with the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    string[] arr = new string[10];
    int i =  0;

    DataTable getdata = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[1]; 
        {
            if (cell != null && (cell.Value != null))
            {
                arr[i] = cell.Value.ToString();
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.
- Corix